# how to compile TCP_cubic.c

Tags: linux, tcp, congestion-control

I'm very new to the Linux kernel. I need modify the tcp cubic algorithm. What's the best way to recompile tcp_cubic.c? Download the kernel source file and recompile the entire kernel?

Comment: Note that if you just want to configure the parameters, you can simply echo new values to files under `/sys/module/tcp_cubic/parameters` instead of recompiling then entire kernel. Recompile is only needed if you want to apply custom source code patches or modify the kernel by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your changes, go to the linux directory (top level of the kernel source), and do

```
make modules bzImage
```

Comment: Make sure, however, that the algorithm is included.(you have `CONFIG_TCP_CONG_CUBIC=y` (or `m`) in `.config` If you want to play with this, it might be better to configure it as a module instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At the end, I compile the tcp_cubic.c as a kenel module following the link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html